# Excel VBA Create Workbook and populate with sheets

Tags: excel, vba

***(Excel 2007)***

I have two pieces of code.

One creates and saves a new Excel workbook:

```
Sub NewWorkBook()

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
   With NewBook
   .SaveAs Filename:="NewBook.xlsx"
   End With

End Sub
```

The other creates worksheets:

```
Public Sub CreateWorksheets()

Dim n As Integer
n = 1
Dim WrkSheet As Worksheet
For n = 1 To 31
  If n > Worksheets.Count Then
  Set WrkSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
  Else
  Set WrkSheet = Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
  End If
WrkSheet.Name = n
Next n
End Sub
```

I need to use these to create 'Workbook B' and populate it with worksheets, but all the code must run from 'Workbook A'.

I can get the first sub to create the workbook, but the CreateWorksheets sub will only work on the workbook containing the code - and then only once I have deleted all but one sheet.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you qualify your objects' up to what workbook they are in, in your second macro, that will work - e.g., instead of using `If n > Worksheets.Count Then` use `If n > Workbooks("NewBook.xlsx").Worksheets.Count Then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Sub NewWorkBookAndSheets()
 Dim NewBook As Workbook
 Dim n As Integer
 Dim start As Integer

 Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
 With NewBook
     start = .Worksheets.Count + 1
     if start < 31 then 

     For n = start  To 31
          .Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(n - 1)
     Next n
     For n = 1 To 31
        .Worksheets(n).Name = n
     Next n
     end if
    .SaveAs Filename:="NewBook.xlsx"
 End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: Spot on! Thanks for a speedy reply.